# hardware emulation

Tags: hardware, driver, robot, device-emulation

I need to write controlling software for a very specialized and fairly complex industrial robot. I'm not allowed to access the actual robot before testing the final software, because it has to work all the time. It would be necessary to somehow emulate the robot, so I can develop my code. I have drivers for the robot, and some manuals but since it is a complex stuff, I would prefer not to build a simulator from scratch.

What I'm looking for is a software where I just load the device drivers and based on them, the hardware can be simulated, with all of its capabilities.

Does something like that exists out there or am I on a completely wrong track?

PS. No, I don't have very good programming skills, but I'm ready to learn :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some generic processor emulators like KVM , Qemu which make use your specific hardware virtually .But you need some thing specific which should be supported and delivered by robot manufacture .

Comment: Can you get some data traces, that is, what's being sent to the robot and its responses? That could help as you could build your simulator and test it to some degree with that data.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Robot manufacturers supply simulation / emulation software.
Eg.

- Nachi robotics haveAX/FD on desk,
- Adept robots have Adept Ace(http://www.adept.com/products/software/pc/adept-ace/general)
- Kuka haveKUKA SIM
- .... and so on

In these programs you can create robot programs, simulate robot movement and interface with all Inputs and outputs. You can also import programs already running on the robot and alter/debug them offline

I believe that creating a simulation/emulation of the entire robot would be a ginormous amount of work, especially if you don't have a lot of experience with programming.